# Как сделать вывод сообщения в div без javascript?

Tags: html

https://pastebin.com/WHyvCDCm . Делаю чат!. Нужно что бы выводило сообщение в div без скриптов.

Comment: Но компьютер можно использовать?

Comment: @Igor в интернете все только с JS а я видел без.

Comment: кхм, кхм... видели, но не помните - где?

Comment: @Igor http://rchatrhoslytqrrt.onion / http://danschatjr7qbwip.onion

Comment: Без JS это будет работать только если: 1. сервер будет пушить всю страницу заново клиенту, 2. используется то-то типа flash или applet и т.д. P.S. ваши обе ссылки битые и не открываются.

Comment: @Axenow Да, я так и предполагал что бы вся страница обновлялась. А без flash и applet и без html5. Просто на чистом PHP.